# Антонимы к слову "выемка"

Tags: лексика

Всякое углубление на плоскости мы имеем право назвать выемкой, а что до всякой выпуклости, выдающейся части? Помогите подобрать антоним.

Answer (score 4):

Прямой антоним "выемки" - "выступ". Из словаря антонимов:

> ВЫСТУП — ВЫЕМКА
>
> *Наверное, я сморщился, когда надел оба ботинка...
>
> Удивительно не совпадали всякие там линии моей ноги с линиями колодки.
>
> Где выступ — там выемка, и наоборот. В. Солоухин. Прекрасная Адыгене.*

Answer (score 1):

Для ***всякой выпуклости*** можно подобрать достаточное количество антонимов (кроме основного) — всё зависит от того, **что именно** вы описываете и в каком контексте.

Вот некоторые: бугор (бугорок), шишка, горб (горбик, горбинка), нарост, вздутие (вздутость), вы́пуклина, вы́пучина.

*У перехода язычка в дверку он сужается, образуя небольшие округлые **выемки**. <...>  Вокруг дверки, по телу бляхи проходят семь **выпуклин** с мелкими наколами у основания.*
[Р. Ф. Воронина. Об одном обереге Крюково-Кужновского могильника](http://annales.info/volga/small/mordob.htm)

*Этот едва образовавшийся лед начал тороситься, образуя сначала выпучину в виде холма, затем вершина холма становилась более остроугольной, а сама **выпучина** — круче.*
Н. Кузнецов. Забытые герои Арктики. Люди и ледоколы